# Network error IOException while trying to Sync Data From SQL Server

Tags: android, sql-server, sql-server-2008, android-emulator, proxy

I'm trying to fetch data from my Local-Server Using an Android App. I established this using jtds.jdbc Connection. In Emulator It's working fine and fetching Data. While tried to connect using Android device through USB it's Giving the Following Error.

```
07-05 06:05:32.790: W/Error connection(4660): Network error IOException: failed to connect to /194.178.100.3 (port 1433): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

Here is the code which i'm using to connect SQL-Server Database

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://194.178.100.3:1433/MyDB",
                                "sa", "password");
```

I have Some Proxy Setting in My System i Doubt is that Blocking me while trying to access Server-Database. While syncing From USB device from my Computer.
My Operating System is Windows 7 Professional, Service Pack 1

Please Help me to Solve this issue.

[image: TELNET SCREEN SHOT]

Answer (score 0):

"Network is unreachable" error occurs when the host is not reachable. Meaning that your application can't connect to the host. This can be due to a number of reasons from you being in a different network that's separate from the one you're trying to connect to.

If you are running the simulator in the same computer that the database is located, try to change 194.178.100.3 to 127.0.0.1 and see if it works.

Comment: I'm able to connect to server(194.178.100.3) from my PC using Emulator . But while i try by connecting Android Device through USB cable and tried to Sync Then i Got this Error..The Database is Sitting in Server not in My Personal Computer. Anyway i'll Try your suggested method.

Comment: Actually  194.178.100.3 is my Server IP..Not mine my Computers ip is Different. I dont think if i mention 127.0.0.1 it will work

Comment: When you connect your Android device through USB, do you connect it to your server or your machine?

Comment: I connect Android device to my Computer and in Eclipse i run my application in debuggable mode. Then i'm getting the following Error in my LogCat. In manifest i mentioned permission also  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>

Comment: Check if your firewall allows Eclipse to make external connections. I know sometimes on my Windows, Java is denied access to other networks.

Comment: Yes.. Eclipse,Java Having Domain permission in Firewall.

Comment: But i don't think thats the issue...Is there anything else will run behind when syncing will happen or maybe we have to configure proxy-settings in Our Android device also. I think firewall is making Trouble but i'm not able to find-out..

Comment: from your machine that's running eclipse, can you try telnet 194.178.100.3 1433 on your command prompt? see if that port is open first.

Comment: Don't Know how to check what you said "194.178.100.3 1433 on your command prompt? "

Comment: If you're using windows, press the windows key + R. The run window will pop up, then type cmd on the field "open". Then press "ok". You will see the command prompt. Therein type 

"telnet 194.178.100.3 1433"

Comment: You can ping, but trying a telnet will let you know if the port 1433 is accepting connections.

Comment: "'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file" i got this msg when i typed the above command

Comment: Ok. I will assume you're using windows. Follow these steps to enable telnet:

http://www.fettesps.com/windows-7-enable-telnet/

Comment: Now i type the command i got a blank black window Telnet 194.178.100.3

Comment: Tried again now i got this Error in LogCat W/Error connection(2613): Network error IOException: failed to connect to /194.178.100.3 (port 1433): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)

Comment: Can you share exactly what you get when you run the telnet? A screen shot can be good.

Comment: I tried and telnet ipaddress port it not showing any error it showed blank screen on cmd prompt.

Comment: Ok. at least we can rule out the connectivity issue. Your connection to the server is ok. Let me see if there is something I can come up with on my end for a test.

Comment: Okay...So solving this issue i have to go and check further :) Anyway thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake of leaving my tablet in flight mode. Just ensure that you haven't done that.